# Autoplot time series - set fixed months/years to plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series

```
library(fpp)
library(forecast)

ausbeer.train <- window(ausbeer, end=c(1999,4))
ausbeer.test <- window(ausbeer, start=c(2000,1))

autoplot(ausbeer.train, xlab="Rok", ylab="beer") +
  autolayer(snaive(ausbeer.train, h=32), PI=FALSE, series="snaive") +
  autolayer(meanf(ausbeer.train, h=32), PI=FALSE, series="meanf") +
  autolayer(ausbeer.test)
```

produces

[image: such image]

What if I wanted to plot only data from 1995 up to 2008? Can I somehow limit the range on the x axis? I don't want to subset my data (as snaive and meanf and probably other methods will need the entire train data), I only need to limit what I draw on the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If p is the value of the autoplot statement in the question then this will plot only 1995 to the end of the series.

```
library(ggplot2)

p + xlim(1995, NA)
```

Comment: You also need to `library(ggplot2)`. Thank you, it worked!